# Regex containing two specific characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex, which is not working:

```
@"^[a-z]{1}[a-z0-9\-_(%i)]*$"
```

The user is allowed to use `%i`, but only in this combination. Only `%` is not allowed. The expression in parentheses does not work.

The user input could be for example:

- testing123%i
- testing123
- testing-%i-123

But this is not allowed:

- testing%123

Comment: What is your string and what are you trying to match.

Comment: What is the code where the regex is used in? You might try `[a-z0-9_-]|%i`, but it does not have to work for you.

Comment: Could you provide *some examples*?

Comment: [a-z0-9\-_]?(%i)?[a-z0-9\-_]?   You may need to add + if you have multiples.

Comment: BTW, did you put the parentheses in an attempt to match `%i` as a *sequence* inside a character class? This could not have worked since a character class only matches 1 single char.

Comment: How do you differenciate between `i` in `testing` and `-%i-`. Do you have rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A character class only matches 1 single char. You need to take `%i` out of the character class if you want to match `%i` as a *sequence*:

```
^[a-z](?:[a-z0-9_-]|%i)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qDfFD9/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `[a-z]` - a lowervase ASCII letter
- `(?:[a-z0-9_-]|%i)*` - zero or more occurrences of:

  - `[a-z0-9_-]` - a lowercase ASCII letter, a digit, `_` or `-`
  - `|`  - or
  - `%i` - a literal char sequence `%i`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: **Note** that you may unroll the alternation to make the regex more efficient: [`^[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*(?:%i[a-z0-9_-]*)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/qDfFD9/2).

Answer (score 1):

string pattern = @"\b(?!(?:.\B)*(.)(?:\B.)*\1)[%i]+\b";

```
    string input = "testing123%i";
    if (Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern))
    {
        return true;
    }
```